# U.S asylee approved / Mexico visit

Tags: customs-and-immigration, mexico, refugees

I have a refugee travel document and was granted asylum but I don’t have a green card / permanent resident card. I have my I-94 stamped and would like to visit Mexico. Would I need a visa to enter Mexico?

Comment: Not posting as an answer because I don’t know the relevance of the I-94 stamp. [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b) says: Visa exemptions: Passengers with a Permanent Resident or Resident Alien Card (Form I-551) issued by USA for a maximum stay of 180 days.

Passengers with a Permit to Re-Enter (Form I-327) issued by the USA for a maximum stay of 180 days.

Passengers with a US Travel Document (Form I-571) issued to refugees for a maximum stay of 180 days.